# Submersible well pump runs but won't pump

Tags: well, well-pump

Pulled my submersible well pump to check for shorts in the wires. Everything looked good. Turned on power and the pump started running. Lowered pump back in the well and it won't pump water. I don't have water line hooked back up to house. was gonna check and make sure pump was pumping water before i hooked water line back to house. I can feel the vibration of the pump running but not getting any water. The pump is about 12 years old.

Comment: Dry well?   Perhaps the pump is not submerged.

Answer (score 0):

It's either not in water, or it's broken and does not pump water any more.